# Why require proper for very ample line bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Vakil's excellent notes.

Definition: A line bundle $L$ on $X \to Spec(A)$ is very ample if  the latter map is proper, and $L$ is the pullback of $O(1)$ under a representation of $X$ as some $Proj(S_*)$ (which is finitely generated in degree $1$; I assume this about all further graded rings so I won't repeat this).

I much prefer the next definition he gives as equivalent:

A line bundle $L$ on $X \to Spec(A)$ is very ample if $X \to Spec(A)$ is proper and there is a closed embedding $X \to \mathbb{P}^n_A$ s.t that $O(1)$ pulls back to $X$.

**My question**

Aren't all the properness requirements unneeded? I claim this both in the original definition and the latter equivalent one. With regards to the equivalent; If $X \to \mathbb{P}^n_A$ is a closed embedding, then $X \to Spec(A)$ is proper (because projective space is proper and compositions of proper are proper); so the following definition of very ample holds; just a pullback of $O(1)$ via some closed embedding in some $X \to \mathbb{P}^n_A$.

With regards to the original definition; Don't assume that $X \to Spec(A)$ is proper, and only $O(1)$ $L=O(1)$ under a representation of $X$ as some $Proj(S_*)$. Then if $S_*$ is generated by $s_0, ..., s_n$, then I claim our resulting map $X \to \mathbb{P}^n_A$ is a closed embedding.

**Proof that the map is a closed embedding**
The resulting map $A[x_0, ... x_n] \to S_*$ is a surjective maps of graded rings, so the kernel is a homogenous ideal so $X$ is given by a homogeneous ideal.

**Summary**
I don't understand why we assume properness since it seems to follow from the other conditions.
I must be wrong, so please correct my mistake, and then explain why it's a useful technical detail to restrict to proper maps in advance?

Comment: In the literature, very ampleness is defined so that it typically (i.e. $X$ is finite-type over $A$) only implies that there is a (possibly not closed) immersion $X \to \mathbb{P}^n_A$. (See Stacks tag 02NP.) It seems Vakil wanted to make a simplifying assumption in his notes and only work in a setting where the immersion is closed. By assuming properness, he ensures that his definition of very ampleness coincides with the usual one in the literature when they both apply.

Comment: @BrianShin Thanks for your comment. I couldn't understand from your answer if you agree that it follows from his other assumption though, or if I've made a mistake in the deduction.

Comment: You're deduction is correct and properness is a consequence of the other conditions Vakil assumes. However, be warned that in the world beyond Vakil's notes, "very ample" has a slightly different definition which does not imply properness.

Comment: @BrianShin Excellent thanks, can you put this as an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of very ampleness that is used in practice is different fron the one that Vakil uses in his notes. In particular, the definition in the literature typically* only implies that there is a (*not* necessarily closed!!) immersion $X→\mathbb{P}^n_A$. (See Stacks tag 02NP.)

Your deduction is correct: the assumption of properness is superfluous, given the other assumptions Vakil makes.

It seems Vakil wanted to make a simplifying assumption in his notes and only work in a setting where the immersion is closed. By assuming properness, he ensures that his definition of very ampleness coincides with the usual one in the literature when they both apply.

*e.g. $X$ is finite-type over $A$